# Error using bytecode-compiling filter, PERL

Tags: perl, compilation, binary, bytecode

When I compile using: `pp -I lib -f Bytecode -o myapp_binary_bytecode myapp`

I get this error:

```
"my" variable $fh masks earlier declaration in same scope at /Library/Perl/5.12/PAR/Filter/Bytecode.pm line 60.
Can't locate B/Bytecode.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at (eval 1) line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
Cannot transform /var/folders/cd/rwsp63c15bb01r89z76_bvr40000gn/T/Q3ubgSUe8P to /var/folders/cd/rwsp63c15bb01r89z76_bvr40000gn/T/LIcOpNf_Oh: No such file or directory (512)
```

Although the compiled binary works, but how can I fix the error?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like I need to install bytecode module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says you're trying to use a [module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?B%3a%3aBytecode) Perl can't locate. The usual cause is that you don't have that module installed.

A lack of permissions to read the module file could also lead to that error, but that's almost never the problem.

Comment: I installed the module, and then program seems to compile with a different error but this exact same error appears on RUNNING the binary

Answer (score 0):

Unrelatedly, I would look into that `my` problem. As to why the running binary still has that problem, `pp` can easily miss dependencies, but it has a dynamic way to counter that problem. Try running `pp -x script` and it will run the script to find any run-time dependencies. Also I think there's a switch for manually adding dependencies to the list.